# JavaScript slides in but fails to slide out

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this simple JavaScript code that is supposed to side a div in and a div out. it is working perfectly when it comes to sliding in. By working perfectly is sliding the div easily. However when you click slideout the div just disappears from the browser. I don't know why and I cant find a fault. My code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <script>
           
            function slideIt()
            {
                var stopPosition = 50;
                var slidingDiv = "";
                slidingDiv = document.getElementById("d3");
                if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) < stopPosition )
                {
                    slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 2 + "px";
                    setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
                }
            }

            function slideOut()
            {
                var startPosition =-150;
                var slidingDiv = "";
                slidingDiv = document.getElementById("d4");
                if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) > startPosition )
                {
                    slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) - 2 + "px";
                    setTimeout(slideOut(), 1);

                }
            }
              
        </script>
        <div id="d1" onclick="slideIt();">Slide in</div>
        <div id="d2" onclick="slideOut();">Slide out</div>
        <div id="d3" style="position: absolute; left:-150px; top:300px" >horizontally sliding div</div>
        <div id="d4" style="position: absolute; left:150px; top:300px">horizontally sliding div</div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried even looking at the javascript console? It should be obvious from there.

Comment: A jsFiddle would be awesome.

Comment: Yeah..The code is clean. No errors.

Comment: Js fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/njueukavi/j954Y/2/, but got it fixed here http://jsfiddle.net/cctqf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invoke `slideOut` in the second timeout. Remove the parentheses.

```
setTimeout(slideOut, 1);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/cctqf/

Comment: Thanks man...works!!...but do you have an idea of how I can remove the railing dots after the div slides out?